# Types in Functions

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Hello I am new to Typescript and I would like to know why this returns an error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'".

```
function addNumber(num1 : any, num2 : any) {
    console.log(num1 + num2)
    return num1 + num2;
}

addNumber(1, 3);
```

When you add Types to the Function Parameters. But without the parameters, the code works fine.

```
function addNumber(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 + num2)
    return num1 + num2;
}

addNumber(1, 3);
```

This does not return an error. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to use the TypeScript compiler `tsc` to turn TypeScript code into JavaScript, which (among other things) removes type annotations.  If you try to run TypeScript code directly in a JavaScript runtime, you will very likely get syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you very much